# Cannot obtain token...site not reachable

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using the sample code provided by DocuSign quickstarts. That code requires me to obtain an access token.

It says to visit the link below in order to obtain the token:

https://developers.hqtest.tst/oauth-token-generator

I get error message:

This site can’t be reached.
developers.hqtest.tst’s server IP address could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Very sorry, the url you have there is a test/internal url which should not have been published. If you can point me to where you found it - w'ell fix it.
The correct url for our token generator is: https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator